# How to connect hard fabric?

Tags: repair

I am trying to repair my backpack whose straps wore down. I decided to replace them with bands of heavy duty plastic-like fabric that I found. Unfortunately, it is very hard for me to push a sewing needle through the bands. I can do it if I grip the needle with pliers and apply all my force.

[image]

In the end, I used a metal band with some bolt nuts. The solution seems to work, but I am afraid that the sharp edges will cut me open like a trout one day. Also for some reason people collecting money for charity organizations no longer stop me on the street.

[image]

My mom has a sewing machine, but she seems reluctant to let me use it. I am also not sure whether it will be strong enough to pierce through the fabric.

Is there some simpler way to connect such sturdy pieces of fabric?

Comment: This site is for [diy.se]; please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: Yupps, sorry, I fooled myself by the name "diy.stackexchange"

Comment: If you're ok with still using some bolts or whatever, you could try eyelets (like on a tarp) instead of strapping. You'll need eyelet pliers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it to a shoe repair shop they can sew it together and the tow straps I had repaired cost less than 5$.